# How to resolve Uncaught Error: Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I've searched, but cannot find a good answer for this.

This function works when I use just use current user. However what it should do is use the value stored in the variable `friendRequest` to query results that already exist in parse. The `FriendRequest` variable is populated once the user clicks on one of the images being displayed on the page within the `div id container`

I get the following error and I'm not sure how to fix it? Is it because `FriendRequest` is undefined?

> Uncaught Error: Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object

Screen shot attached.

**Here is the function returning the error.**

```
   function FriendProfile() {

    var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");
    var friendRequest = new FriendRequest();
    friendRequest.id = window.selectedFriendRequestId;


    var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

    query.equalTo("SentTo", friendRequest);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
            imageURLs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                imageURLs.push(object.get('BadgeName'));
            }
            // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
            for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

**Here is how the friendRequest variable is populated .**

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

        var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
        query.include('toUser');
        query.include("myBadge");
        query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
        query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                var friends = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                        friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                        username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username')
                    });
                }

                // TW: replaced dynamic HTML generation with wrapper DIV that contains IMG and name DIV
                _.each(friends, function (item) {
                    // using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
                    var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper" data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"></div>');
                    wrapper.append('<img class="images" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                    $('#container').append(wrapper);
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });


         ///SECTION 2 -Click/Select friend image to be captured and used with section 3//////////

         // set up event handler
        $('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function () {
            console.log(this);
             FriendProfile();
            var wrapper = $(this);
            console.log(wrapper.data('friendRequestId'));
            // remove selected from all wrappers in case one was already selected
            $('#container .wrapper').removeClass('selected');
            // mark clicked wrapper as selected
            wrapper.addClass('selected');
            // save friendRequestId as a global that can be read by other code
            window.selectedFriendRequestId = wrapper.data('friendRequestId');
            // enabled button
            $('#simulateAddBadge').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.go').click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
                               $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');

            });
            return false;

        });
```

[image]

Comment: If `window.selectedFriendRequestId` is not set when `FriendProfile()` is called, then you will get an error. Add `console.log(window.selectedFriendRequestId)` in there to help you debug.

Comment: That fixes it, but uncovers more questions. I will accept the comment as the answer if you add it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `window.selectedFriendRequestId` is not set when `FriendProfile()` is called, then you will get an error. Add `console.log(window.selectedFriendRequestId);` in there to help you debug.

You need to examine the logic you are after, you might instead want to make the `friendRequestId` a parameter of the function and extract the value in the click handler and pass it as a parameter. Currently your "SECTION 2" code is calling the function then setting the value afterwards.

Simplified example:

```
function FriendProfile(friendRequestId) {
    // query based on friendRequestId ...
}

// other code that calls function
$('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function () {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    var friendRequestId = wrapper.data('friendRequestId');
    FriendProfile(friendRequestId);
    // other code ...
});
```