# Changing the objectId thats returned in a query to that of the actual user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

This is what I'm attempting to achieve.

A list of users (friends) is returned on the page to the user, They can then click on one of these users and the page is updated to list all of that users items (which are basically images).

**This query works correctly and returns a list of users.**

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

        var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
        query.include('toUser');
        query.include('SentTo');
        query.include("myBadge");
        query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
        query.equalTo("status", "Request sent");

        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                var friends = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    friends.push({
                        imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                        friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                        username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username')  

                    });
                }

                // TW: replaced dynamic HTML generation with wrapper DIV that contains IMG and name DIV
                _.each(friends, function (item) {
                    // using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
                    var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper" data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"></div>');
                    wrapper.append('<img class="images" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                    $('#container').append(wrapper);
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
```

****This below query should contain the user who  has selected above and stored in window.selectedFriendRequestId (which is saved in the variable friendRequest  ****

This query looks at the myBadges class and the user reference "SentTo" the ref used is for example a3aePaphBF which is the actual _User objectID.

```
 function FriendProfile() {

    var friendRequest = "window.selectedFriendRequestId";
    console.log(window.selectedFriendRequestId);

    var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

    query.equalTo("SentTo", friendRequest);
    query.find({
        success: function (results) {
            // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
            imageURLs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                imageURLs.push(object.get('BadgeName'));
            }
            // If the imageURLs array has items in it, set the src of an IMG element to the first URL in the array
            for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                $('#imgs').append("<img src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

---

The issue is that the first query is not returning an objectId that I can use in the second query as a reference. For example a3aePaphBF is not returned but cr3LG70vrF is.

How to I return the actual _User objectid in the first query so I can make these match?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID of a user:

```
results[i].get('toUser').id
```

So if you update your section of code that is doing `friends.push(...)`:

```
friends.push({
    imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
    friendRequestId: results[i].id,
    username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
    userId: results[i].get('toUser').id
});
```

Then in your bit where you create the wrapper:

```
_.each(friends, function (item) {
    // using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
    var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"'
        + ' data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"'
        + ' data-to-user-id="' + item.userId + '"></div>');
    wrapper.append('<img class="images" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
    wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
    $('#container').append(wrapper);
});
```

Notice that I've added another data-property to hold the ID of the toUser.

Now if you followed the tips from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594975/how-to-resolve-uncaught-error-cant-serialize-an-unsaved-parse-object-error-mes), you can tweak the code that attaches the on-click handler to pass `toUserId` also:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function () {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    var friendRequestId = wrapper.data('friendRequestId');
    var toUserId = wrapper.data('toUserId');
    FriendProfile(friendRequestId, toUserId);
    // other code ...
});
```

Lastly your `FriendProfile()` function can now use either of those parameters as needed:

```
function FriendProfile(friendRequestId, toUserId) {
    var toUser = new Parse.User();
    toUser.id = toUserId;

    var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

    query.equalTo("SentTo", toUser);
    // ... etc ...
}
```

NOTE: The `User` class should be locked down for privacy reasons, you shouldn't be able to read any properties of other users except in Cloud Code when you have the following line in your Cloud Function:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Re the _User class, surely I must be able to query another user and display their activity to other users without cloud code. I'm already doing this for multiple users via an activity feed... I'll need to look at it, but the code edits above are returning undefined at the mo..

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks, I'm actually truing to query the mybadges class and return the badges that belong to the user that has been captured in friendRequest, really to show a list of that users activity.So in the variable friendRequest I actually want the a3aePaphBF ref not the one being returned so that the query works. If that makes sense~?

Comment: Perhaps update your question with the classes and their columns for any related classes and a description of what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten the question to try and make it clearer if that helps?

Comment: Sorry @Timothy Walters - I didn't seem to get an alert for your update. Thank you, I've tweaked based on your suggestions. Just a little uncertain about poisoning the "$('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function () {" code section. For illustration only I've added the latest code to this Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2vQvY/ If you could just cast your eye over it and let me know if I've followed correctly I can close of the question. Many thanks.

Comment: @Dano007 your jsfiddle is a little hard to follow as it contains repeated bits of code (variable definitions and even a whole block of code for the #send click handler). The #container click handler should probably be inside one of your `$(document).ready(...)` blocks just to be safe.